# How to get the key of a child value with Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have code that triggers when a user_course is added

```
export const writePesertaMatkul = functions.database
.ref('/user_course/{user_uid}/') // query child yg dipantau
.onCreate((snapsot, context) => {   // on create trigered
    const user_uid = context.params.user_uid;
    const matkulData = snapsot.val(); //dataSnapshot

    });
```

The log value is `{ courses_5: 'PEMROGRAMAN GUI' }` its doing great, but one problem here. I just want to store `courses_5`. How to achieve it?

SOLUTION

```
export const writePesertaMatkul = functions.database
.ref('/user_course/{user_uid}/{matkul_id}') // query child yg dipantau
.onCreate((snapsot, context) => {   // on create trigered
    const user_uid = context.params.user_uid;
    const matkulData = snapsot.val(); //dataSnapshot
    const matkulID = context.params.matkul_id;


    // const matkulKey = snapsot.key;
    console.log("keynya :", snapsot.key);
    console.log("uidnya  :", user_uid);


    const updates = {}; 
    updates[snapsot.key + "/" + user_uid] = "true";

    return admin.database().ref('/course_peserta/').update(updates);;
    });
```

use this code for get the parent `snapsot.key`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `key` property of a DataSnapshot, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key

So,

```
const matkulKey = snapsot.key;
```

should do the trick.

*(Note that you use the variable name `snapsot` in your code, and not `snapshot`)*

Comment: I'd change the code , but the deploy going error. I want triger when course inside uid added

Comment: @yehezkielyehezkiel If you make important changes to your initial question (here the path that triggers the Cloud Function) you should better ask a new question. As a matter of fact, the question and the answer are kind of "decoupled" now and it may be difficult for possible future readers to understand them. **I took the liberty to revert back your question to its initial state**: please ask a new question which details your new problem.